# $(this).hide(); doesn't close the popup div no matter what. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, hide

I'm struggling to close a popup window, which is shown on a click, but it doesn't work for some reason that is not obvious to me.

Here is HTML structure:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h2>Some title</h2>
        <div class="red-divider"></div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="popup">Description 1</div>
                <div class="btn1"></div>
                <p>some text goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="popup">Description 2</div>
                <div class="btn2"></div>
                <p>some text goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="popup">Description 3</div>
                <div class="btn3"></div>
                <p>some text goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="popup">Description 4</div>
                <div class="btn4"></div>
                <p>some text goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="popup">Description 5</div>
                <div class="btn5"></div>
                <p>some text goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS styles:

```
.btn {
width: 190px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.btn1,.btn2,.btn3,.btn4,.btn5 {
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

.popup {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width: 500px;
margin-left: -250px;
height: 200px;
margin-top: -200px;
padding: 25px 10px 30px 10px;
color: #fff;
background: rgba(47,47,47,0.8);
z-index:1000;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        $('.popup').hide();
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
    });

    $('.popup').on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

So, when I click each button, it successfully closes existing popup div and opens correct one. That means that 1st `$('.popup').hide();` does work, but

the 2nd `$(this).hide();` doesn't work. I tried `$('.popup').hide();` and still no luck. The thing is that I used this code to close popups like this few times before and it worked perfectly.

Also, in the beginning I had this line for showing the popup div `$(this).next('.popup').show();` but it didn't work until `.next()` was changed to `.find()`. Just don't get it, can someone please explain what's the difference? It should work both ways.

I'm beginner in jQ, probably missing some basic stuff.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: .next() selector gets siblings, .find() gets children and grandchildren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropogation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) to prevent the `.btn` click event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        $('.popup').hide();
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
    });

    $('.popup').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

The `.popup` is inside the div `.btn`. while clicking on `.popup` div both will be triggered , that's why it doesn't hide.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2wfu9m4y/)**

Comment: Thank you @Sam1604, for more visual version.

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario btn click event being called when you click on the popup as its parent element of that. hence popup showing again and again.  you have option to prevent it in jquery it's call stopPropagation.

event.stopPropagation() is a method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

here you need to pass event object as argument here i have used 'e'
correct your code ass follow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  

    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
       $('.popup').hide();
       $(this).find('.popup').show();
    });

    $('.popup').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks the same to me either. May be @Feroza didn't see previous answer yet.

Comment: it's.. just noticed... it's important to give clear anwser  so beginners will understand throughly